# Integrating spark and spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

After fighting with logger dependencies, I finally started successfully the spring boot application with the usual "java -jar" command.

In the application there is a REST service in which it is used Spark to extract data from Oracle and MongoDB. 
When I called this REST service I got this exception:

```
Driver stacktrace:
Job 0 failed: treeAggregate at MongoInferSchema.scala:80, took 0.233175 s
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.16.212.49, executor 0): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoPartition
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoPartition
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Closing MongoClient: [127.0.0.1:27017]
```

The pom.xml contains the mongodb dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the compiled Jar contains the mongodb libraries:

```
....
825351 Mon Jul 30 14:42:22 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.0.jar
1897919 Mon May 28 23:33:28 CEST 2018 BOOT-INF/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.6.4.jar
....
```

I tried to add the libraries in the classpath too, but with no result.

Has anyone an idea how to get Spark to see the jars it needs?

EDIT:

Following the suggestion of @Ramdev, I added this portion of code to my code:

```
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
    context.addJar("/home/user/.m3/repository/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.3.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.0.jar");
    context.addJar("/home/user/.m3/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.8.1/mongo-java-driver-3.8.1.jar");
```

The result is Spark now sees the jars, but it seems to be in conflict with the ones in the applicacation jar:

```
018-09-25 11:39:51 ERROR [dispatcherServlet]:182 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.countDocuments(Lorg/bson/conversions/Bson;)J] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.countDocuments(Lorg/bson/conversions/Bson;)J
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoSamplePartitioner$$anonfun$7.apply(MongoSamplePartitioner.scala:88)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoSamplePartitioner$$anonfun$7.apply(MongoSamplePartitioner.scala:88)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withCollectionDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:186)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withCollectionDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:184)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:171)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:171)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:154)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:171)
        at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withCollectionDo(MongoConnector.scala:184)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoSamplePartitioner.partitions(MongoSamplePartitioner.scala:88)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.DefaultMongoPartitioner.partitions(DefaultMongoPartitioner.scala:34)
        at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.getPartitions(MongoRDD.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.ShuffleDependency.<init>(Dependency.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec.inputRDDs(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:386)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BaseLimitExec$class.inputRDDs(limit.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalLimitExec.inputRDDs(limit.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:605)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
        at my.app.common.spark.SparkSpringBootHandler.querySpark(SparkSpringBootHandler.java:92)
```

SparkSpringBootHandler.java:85-92 lines

```
 String queryJ = "select count(s.idlocalizator) "
                + "from installationOnBoard i join storicpos s on s.installation_uuid = i.uuid ";

 result += sdf.format(new Date()) + " - ***************** QUERY ***************** Start...\n";

 Dataset<Long> counter = sparkSession.sql(queryJ).as(Encoders.LONG());

 counter.show();
```

Comment: can you check is class `com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoPartition` part of build-jars?

Comment: Yes, it belongs to mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.0.jar and it is part of the application jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are integrating Spark jobs and Spring Boot. I am sharing my views based on what I did in one project.

We had a separate project for Spark/Scala and building a fat jar with all dependency using sbt assembly.

On the Spring Boot project side, we were calling Spark job using Apache Livy API and tracking status of the job using Apache Livy generated batch Id.

Apache Livy is available for both Spark 1.x and Spark 2.x

https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html

I hope it may help in some direction.

Comment: to give you an idea of how I use Spark within Spring boot application, you can take a look at this example https://github.com/Zhuinden/spring-spark-example/tree/master/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/sparkexperiment. I followed his steps, but instead of using a file I connect to two dbs.

Comment: It may be possible that Spark job that is launched is not getting dependency jar from spring boot jar. You may try to use this example from Spark documentation to provide dependency in Spark job launcher. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I edited my question with the new Exception

Comment: Is there any specifc reason that you cannot use version 3.8.1 in your pom <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I didn't see that maven included an older version of mongo drivers! Thanks!! I needed to change my pom dependency to <dependency><groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId><artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId><exclusions><exclusion><groupId>org.mongodb</groupId><artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>              </exclusion></exclusions><version>2.3.0</version></dependency> and then add your suggestion. In this way I could delete the JavaSparkContext addJar lines too. Now it works perfectly :)